# Is there a way to set the font using pdfcanvas in iText when adding a header?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I"m using a page event to add a header and footer in my pdf using iText. The header needs to be a different color, but I'm not sure how to change the color of the text. There doesn't seem to be any function calls to change the text color, like how paragraphs have.

```
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
    if (docEvent.getDocument().getPageNumber(docEvent.getPage()) != 1) {
        try {

            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(docEvent.getPage());
            canvas.beginText();

            canvas.setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE), 24);
            canvas.moveText(50, PageSize.A4.getHeight() - 50)
                    .showText("Header")
                    .endText()
                    .release();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PDFHeaderPageNumberEvt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PdfCanvas` object has a `setFillColorRgb()` method.

```
canvas.moveText(50, PageSize.A4.getHeight() - 50)
                        .setFillColorRgb(255,0,0) // Red
                        .showText("Header")
                        .endText()
                        .release();
```

Will produce your header in red.